# How to pass selected value in dropdown and append in site_url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

How do you get the selected value in dropdown and append it into the site_url? I cant figure out how to do this. Please point me in the right diretion. Thank you.

```
<form name="filterByDate" method="post">
<h3>Filter Suggestion</h3>&nbsp;
    <select name="year">
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option></select>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("suggestion/filter/1/". HOW TO APPEND SELECTED VALUE HERE ."); ?>">Jan</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("suggestion/filter/2"); ?>">Feb</a></li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

I edited the accepted answer below: here is the edited portion:

```
 var linksContainer=document.getElementById("linksContainer");
 linksContainer.innerHTML="<li><a href=\"javascript:window.location('<?php echo site_url(); ?>/suggestion/filter/1/"+selval+"');\">January</a>
```

Comment: I see that code you have given is serverside code i.e. written in php. If you want to update the href attribute with the selected value, then you need to use javascript and generate/update the hyperlinks at client side. See my answer for more info.

Comment: yes i know i need to use javascript here, but how can i put js in the link? will it be possible to use onclick?

Comment: please see my answer below. I have generated the link with the js site_url(.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the code below: (have slightly changed it)

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="filterByDate" method="post">
<h3>Filter Suggestion</h3>&nbsp;
    <select name="year" onchange="generateLinks(this);">
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option></select>

    <!-- <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("suggestion/filter/1/". HOW TO APPEND SELECTED VALUE HERE ."); ?>">Jan</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("suggestion/filter/2"); ?>">Feb</a></li>
    </ul> -->

    <ul id="linksContainer">
    </ul>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function generateLinks(obj){
    var selval=obj[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    var linksContainer=document.getElementById("linksContainer");
    linksContainer.innerHTML="<li><a href=\"javascript:site_url('suggestion/filter/1/"+selval+"');\">Jan</a></li>";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: everytime i changed the dropdown it adds the link however it has alternating values, 2013, 2014, 2013..etc..

Comment: @mmr please try with the updated code. I removed the
linksContainer.innerHTML+= and changed it to linksContainer.innerHTML=

Comment: i modified your code above, site_url is undefined and replaced it with window.location, i know that mixing js and php is a bad idea but i think this is the suitable implementation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Ill use jQuery then,  however id improve on the markup to have classes/IDs for the tags i wanted to target.
Give the select a class/id and use it in the script and the UL and or the link that is to be targeted.

```
function saveUrl($item, url ) {
  $item.attr('data-url', url);
}

 // save all the links original href
 $('ul a').each(function() {
    saveUrl( $(this), $(this).attr('href') );
 });

 // on change make the links go to the actual year
 $('.select-year').on('change', function() {

    var $link = $('ul a'),
         linkDataUrl = $link.attr('data-url'),
         selectedOption = $(this).val(),
         newUrl = linkDataUrl + selectedOption;

    $link.attr('href', newUrl);

 });
```

Comment: Please check your code, there are errors
1. selecetedOption should be selectedOption
2. newUrl = linkUrl + selectedOption this will not work
because the requirement is to replace part of the href attribute
i.e. href="site_url('xyz/"+dynamicvalue+"');"
you have to update the dynamic value which cannot be achieved by simple concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The below will give you the selected text value in dropdown

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
```

and below will give the selected index 
    $("#yourdropdownid ").val()

you can pass the index or text to the anchor to pass url and call a onclick event method
please refer below sample code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myAnchor">Jan</a>
```

js

```
document.getElementById('myAnchor').onclick = function() {
    // this is the <a> in here
    window.location.replace("Pass the value from Dropdown from above methods");
    return false; // optional, prevents href from executing at all 
};
```